# Changing x tick label in group plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df like so:

```
    Year  Month  Day  FID__x  Fuzzy_Anomaly
0   1984      5   17       3       0.048220
1   1984      7    4       3      -0.199825
2   1984      9    6       3      -0.528545
3   1985      5   20       3      -0.176771
4   1985      6   21       3      -0.345946
5   1986      7   26       3      -0.139717
6   1986      8   27       3      -0.071766
7   1987      8   30       3      -0.560004
8   1987      9   15       3      -0.498678
9   1987     10    1       3      -0.484233
10  1988      7   31       3      -0.243202
11  1989      7    2       3      -0.006413
12  1990      6   19       3      -0.538433
```

and I want the tick marks to be a combination of `Year`, `Month`, and `Day` at intervals of 5 (I haven't even attempted to add the interval requirement below)

I am plotting with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

with PdfPages(r'F:\Sheyenne\Fishnet_ROI\graphs\delete.pdf') as pdf:
   for i, group in df.groupby('FID__x'):
       plt.figure()
       Hurst_plots=group.plot(x=['Year', 'Month', 'Day'], y='Fuzzy_Anomaly',title=str(i)).get_figure()
       plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05), ncol=3,
          fancybox=True, shadow=True)
       labels=['19840517', '19840704', '19840906', '19850520', '19850621', '19860726', '19860827', '19870830', '19870915', '19871001', '19880731', '19890702', '19900619']
       plt.xticks(labels)
       plt.ylabel('Values')
       plt.xlabel('Year')
       pdf.savefig(Hurst_plots)  
       plt.close(Hurst_plots)
```

but the resulting graph is completely empty.

Comment: what do you mean saying: `at intervals of 5` - of 5 days, years, months?

Comment: sorry, intervals of 5 years, My real dataframe has years between 1984 and 2011, so intervals of 2 in this scenario would be more practical

Comment: but there would be only two xticks on your xaxis in this case - is that what you want?

Comment: yea so there would be one for 1984, 1987 and 1989

Comment: try this: `xticks = [y for y in range(df.Year.min(), df.Year.max(), 5)]`. How do you expect `1984`, `1987` with a 5 year interval?

Comment: that would be with a two year interval, My real dataframe has years between 1984 and 2011 so 5 will be fine for it.  Using your proposed code since `Year` is a float this won't work and when I use `df.Year=df.Year.astype(int)` this error is returned, `ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer`

Comment: since I know the first year is 1984 and the last is 2011 I used this,`plt.xticks = [y for y in range(1984, 2011, 5)]`, but it didn't work as expected, its still including the `Month` and `Day` on the labels

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend formatting the data into the format you want it first before trying to plot it. Thus, let's assume that you have a dataframe called `df` that contains the columns you listed (Year,  Month,  Day,  FID__x,  Fuzzy_Anomaly).

First create a new column that is a combination of the three date-related columns:

```
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: '{}-{}-{}'.format(row['Year'], row['Month'], row['Day']), axis=1)
```

then set the `Date` column as your index:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

which will make it easy to create the plot your were making:

```
df.groupby('FID__x')['Fuzzy_Anomaly'].plot()
```

`Date` will automatically be your x-axis and it will assign appropriate time intervals and format the dates nicely. Then you can apply your other labels as you already did.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for my grouped plot though?  This would graph all my `FID__x` onto the same graph (plot) when I want separate graphs for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I've intentionally changed your data set, so that it will include years between 1984 and 2011.

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
    Year  Month  Day  FID__x  Fuzzy_Anomaly
0   1984      5   17       3       0.048220
1   1985      5   20       3      -0.199825
2   1985      9    6       3      -0.528545
3   1985     10   20       3      -0.176771
4   1992      6   21       3      -0.345946
5   1994      7   26       3      -0.139717
6   1996      8   27       3      -0.071766
7   1998      8   30       3      -0.560004
8   2000      9   15       3      -0.498678
9   2003     10    1       3      -0.484233
10  2006      7   31       3      -0.243202
11  2009      7    2       3      -0.006413
12  2011      6   19       3      -0.538433

In [10]: xticks = [y for y in range(df.Year.min(), df.Year.max(), 5)]

In [11]: df.plot(x='Year', y='Fuzzy_Anomaly', xticks=xticks)
Out[11]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x48e0e80>
```

PS i have updated the data set so now you have duplicates in `Year`

[image: Plot]

Comment: Yes, that is how I want my axis to look but this won't work with my original data presented.  Since you don't have duplicates in `Year` it plots fine, but I do so I need to plot based on `Year`, `Month` and `Day`, not just `Year`.

Comment: @StefanoPotter, did you test it?

Comment: @StefanoPotter,  I've updated my answer - i've put some duplicates, but i didn't change the code...

Comment: yea I tried it, when I plot by `Year` only the last occurrence of each unique `Year` is plotted, so in your most recent example for `1985` only row `3` would be plotted.